# Preserve VARBINARY value and store it to another variable as varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @Blob VARBINARY(256) = CAST('SOMETHING' AS VARBINARY(256))
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(256)

SELECT @Blob
```

Result of the above query is `0x534F4D455448494E47`

```
SELECT @Var = CAST(@Blob AS varchar)
SELECT @Var
```

I want to save `@Blob` value in a parameter (`@Var`) as `varchar` but it just simply converts it back to 'SOMETHING'. Is there a work around for this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want the hex digits stored as a string? If so, are you sure you really want to do that? Seems pretty useless.

Comment: Yes, I would like to store them in a variable of VARCHAR(256) TYPE. since I am generating custom error and there I have a requirement to show what was the input parameter in hex digits format. I nee to concatenate the string with the hex digits. It can only be achieved if, I convert and preserve the hex digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd just store the bytes in the database, and convert to hex in the application on demand rather than storing the hex in the database. But...

You won't be able to do `varchar(256)`, because if you have 256 bytes in hex, it will be double (512), plus the leading `0x` if you want, for 514 total characters.

But if that's what you want, looks like Microsoft hasn't given you a built-in feature, but they do provide an example, found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104829):

```
create procedure sp_hexadecimal
  @binvalue varbinary(255)
as
declare @charvalue varchar(255)
declare @i int
declare @length int
declare @hexstring char(16)

select @charvalue = '0x'
select @i = 1
select @length = datalength(@binvalue)
select @hexstring = '0123456789abcdef'

while (@i <= @length)
begin

  declare @tempint int
  declare @firstint int
  declare @secondint int

  select @tempint = convert(int, substring(@binvalue,@i,1))
  select @firstint = floor(@tempint/16)
  select @secondint = @tempint - (@firstint*16)

  select @charvalue = @charvalue +
    substring(@hexstring, @firstint+1, 1) +
    substring(@hexstring, @secondint+1, 1)

  select @i = @i + 1

end

select 'sp_hexadecimal'=@charvalue
```